# Vuetify 3 | How to change Icon Color in <v-pagination> componenet?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

I'm working on a project using Vuetify 3 and I'm trying to customize the appearance of the  component. Specifically, I want to change the color of the icons used for previous and next buttons.

```html
  <v-pagination
    v-model="currentPage"
    :length="100"
    :total-visible="total"
    >  
  </v-pagination>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `:color` prop:

```html
<v-pagination
  color="secondary"
  ...
```

but this will change color of all elements.

If you want to change color of individual elements, you have to use CSS:

```css
  .v-pagination__first,
  .v-pagination__prev,
  .v-pagination__item,
  .v-pagination__item--is-active,
  .v-pagination__next,
  .v-pagination__last{
    color: rgb(var(--v-theme-primary));
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, that helped me. Maybe you also know how to replace commas with dots?
[screenshot](https://imgur.com/YBzqfuE)

Comment: That's great! The comma in the numbers is set through [locale settings](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/internationalization/), you just have to pick a locale that uses dots as thousands separator